# Glossaries: parenthesis around page numbers

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have a glossary. Let us say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This process 
is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

[image: latex glossaries]

I like the page numbers after the entry. But how can I enclose them in a parenthesis, or possibly prepend them with some text such as "Page(s): 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out how:

```
\renewcommand{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{(#1)}
```

Inspired by this question: [change latex glossary page number color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129181/change-latex-glossary-page-number-color?rq=1).